# What is making my output far off from the expected

Tags: java

I've been working on this for a while and I can't figure out how I'm butchering the output and calculations maybe I'm just overthinking things and are overstressing myself on the deadline. I'd greatly appreciate some feedback on what I'm doing wrong that the output and calculation is so far off

[image: Expected Output]
[image: Calculations base]

My output

> Welcome to John Doe's Shipping Calculator
>
> Please Enter the Length of the first Package:  1
>
> Please Enter the Width of the First Package:  1
>
> Please Enter the Height of the First Package:  1
>
> Dimensions are: 1.0X1.0X1.0
>
> Please Enter Dimensions of Second Package
>
> Enter Height:2 Enter Length:2 Enter Width:2
>
> Dimensions are: 1.0X1.0X1.0
>
> Package 2 is 5times costly than Package 1
>
> Package 2 is more costly than Package 1 with price difference of $8.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Package {

    private double Length;
    private double Width;
    private double Height;
    private Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    public Package()
    {
        
        Length=1.0;
        Width=1.0;
        Height=1.0;
    }
     public Package(double length, double width, double height) {
         super();
         this.Length = Length;
         this.Width = Width;
         this.Height = Height;
     }
  
    public Package(Package b)
    {
        Length=b.Length;
        Width=b.Width;
        Height=b.Height;
    }
    public void inputLength()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Length:");
        Length=input.nextDouble();
    }
    public void inputWidth()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Width:");
        Width=input.nextDouble();
    }
        
        public void inputHeight()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Height:");
            Height=input.nextDouble();
        }
    
    
       public void displayDimensions()
       {
           System.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X "+ Width + "X" + Height);
       }
    public double calcVolume()
    {
        return Length*Width*Height;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shipment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        double Length=1,Width=1,Height=1;
        double vol1=0,vol2=0,cost1=0,cost2=0;
        System.out.println("Welcome to John Doe's Shipping Calculator");
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Length of the first Package: ");
        Length=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Width of the First Package: ");
        Width=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Height of the First Package: ");
        Height=s.nextDouble();
        
        
        
           {
               System.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X" + Width + "X" +Height);
           }
        
        Package p1=new Package(Length,Width,Height);
        System.out.println("Please Enter Dimensions of Second Package");
        Package p2=new Package();
        p2.inputHeight();
        p2.inputLength();
        p2.inputWidth();
        
        
           
               System.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X" + Width + "X" + Height);
               
        vol1=p1.calcVolume();
        vol2=p2.calcVolume();
        cost1=3+vol1-1;
        cost2=3+vol2-1;
        
        if(cost1==cost2)
            System.out.println("Cost for Both Packages are the same: $"+cost1);
        else
        {
            if(cost1>cost2)
            {
                if(cost1<2*cost2)
                    System.out.println("Package 1 Cost is slightly more than Package 2");
                else if(cost1<3*cost2)
                    System.out.println("Package 1 costs twice as much as Package 2");
                else if(cost1<4*cost2)
                    System.out.println("Package 1 costs triple the amount of Package 2");
                else if(cost1<5*cost2)
                    System.out.println("Package 1 costs quadruple the amount of Package 2");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Package 1 is"+ (int)(cost1/cost2) + "times costly than Package 2");
                System.out.println("Package 1 is more costly than Package 2 with the price difference of: $"+(cost1-cost2));
            }
            
            if(cost2>cost1)
            {
                if(cost2<2*cost1)
                    System.out.println("Package 2 Cost is slightly more than Package 1");
                else if (cost2<3*cost1)
                    System.out.println("Package 2 Costs twice as much as Package 1");
                else if(cost2<4*cost1)
                    System.out.println("Package 2 costs triple the amount of Package 1");
                else if(cost2<5*cost1)
                    System.out.println("Package 2 costs quadruple the amount of Package 1");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Package 2 is "+(int)(cost2/cost1) + "times costly than Package 1");
                System.out.println("Package 2 is more costly than Package 1 with price difference of $"+(cost2-cost1));
            }
            
        }
                
        s.close();
        
    }
            
            

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but in general it's best to use Java naming convention. The first output issue is because you output previously-set values without updating them from the second set of inputs. Using the new package instance would be easier and less error-prone.

Comment: How did you come up with this equation? `3+vol1-1`?

Comment: Also why do you have 3 constructors?

Answer (score 1):

first you set height, width, length

```
 Length=s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please Enter the Width of the First Package: ");
    Width=s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please Enter the Height of the First Package: ");
    Height=s.nextDouble();
```

then make a package
then

`enter code hereSystem.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X" + Width + "X" +Height);`

make a new package
then

`System.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X" + Width + "X" +Height);`

you never change lenght, height,width

you should add a toString() method to your class and call p1.toString() and p2.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Just after read the second package you are showing the variables that you have used to read the parameters of the first package.

```
System.out.println("Dimensions are: "+ Length + "X" + Width + "X" + Height);
```

And they are not updated because of that the dimensions of the second package are wrong